# learning OOP of mysql call in Open Cart

Tags: php, mysql, oop, opencart

I am new to OOP and I had study through Open Cart Code and I am wondering how they actually make the query call in such a short statement of a Controller file. For example:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_customer");
```

I found the **db.php** at public_html/engine folder and query function in the **db.php**.

But how they link over the **db.php** into the controller? or did the Extend Controller do the magic?

Which file is the main core which links all these? If I would like to create my a website of my own, how am I going to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done in index.php. Search for $controller = new Front($registry);. Database layer, and other services, are transfered to controller via $registry.

But I don't think, that is good idea learn OOP from Open Cart. There are huge amount of repetetive code in controllers and models. It's not the best example of good aplication design.

I recomend you, for start with OOP, blog [PHP Design Patterns](http://www.php5dp.com/)

Comment: thank you for your assistance, but the link provided was not as easy and structured as open cart ones. I was wondering which code or file is required to do such simple query function.